# PHP/AJAX constantly return null when i request XML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this cript in javascript.

```
function showItems(type)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create object
    var call = "getitems";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                alert(response);
            }
        }


xmlhttp.open("GET", "scripts/php/ajaxCalls.php?call=" + call + "&type=" + type, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this is the script i got in my PHP file

```
//now use the gathered item ids to return items in proper XML back to javascript.
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><items>";
    $numberOfItems = count($items);

    for($i=0; $i<$numberOfItems; $i++)
    {
        $xml .= "<ITEMS>";
        $itemId[$i] = $items[$i];
        $xml .= "<ID>".$itemId[$i]."</ID>";
        $itemPic[$i] = $itemList[(int)$itemId[$i]][2];
        $xml .= "<PICTURE>".$itemPic[$i]."</PICTURE>";
        $xml .= "</item>";
    }

    $xml .= "</ITEMS>";

    echo $xml;
```

my problem is WHEN i change reponse = xmlhttp.responseXML to xmlhttp.responseText. The response is just fine i get the string i want and it looks like XML. BUT! When i use xmlhttp.responseXML i constantly get NULL as a return value. What am i missing?

Comment: can you also post the xml string(responseText) your getting?

Comment: The XML string looks like this

Comment: you didn't post any xml

Comment: <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?><ITEMS><ITEM><ID>3</ID><PICTURE>chair.png</PICTURE></ITEM></ITEMS>

Comment: Your xml is messed up. You're opening the `<ITEMS>` tag in the loop over and over and never opening the `<item>` tag at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you that your XML wouldn't likely be parsed by any compliant DOM parser since your `<items>` node is in lower case at the top and closed by an uppercase `<ITEMS>`.

[According to the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsexml)

> `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` Returns a Document containing the
>   response to the request, or null if the request was unsuccessful, has
>   not yet been sent, **or cannot be parsed as XML or HTML**. The response is
>   parsed as if it were a text/xml stream. When the responseType is set
>   to "document" and the request has been made asynchronously, the
>   response is parsed as a text/html stream.

Additionally, you may want to send the correct Content-type header along with the response to ensure the client accepts it properly or force the `XMLHttpRequest` object to parse it as XML via `overrideMimeType()` method.

Comment: Yeah that was an error from trying to figure out what to do.. but even when it was corrected it still went wrong

Comment: Well then perhaps consider the `Content-type` header as well. In either case you can use your browser's developer tools to debug any exceptions from the client, which can give you additional clues.

Comment: I just fixed it by adding header('Content-Type: text/xml'); to the PHP file just before i created the string..